# Move parallax per slide progress instead of total progress

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, swiper.js

I'm writing an Ionic 2 app and want to use the Slider component (based on Swiper) to do something similar to this demo: http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/28-parallax.html

But whenever I add a parallax item it moves based on the total slider progress (like the background in the demo) and I found no way to have them move based on a single slide progress (like the text in the demo). ([Swiper docs](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#parallax))

Does anyone know if that's possible? The [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) don't have any details on parallax in slides.

What I tried:

```
<ion-slides parallax progress>
  <ion-slide>
    <h2>No Parallax</h2>
    <p data-swiper-parallax="-100">Parallax: -100</p>
    <p data-swiper-parallax="-200">Parallax: -200</p>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h2>No Parallax</h2>
    <p data-swiper-parallax="-100">Parallax: -100</p>
    <p data-swiper-parallax="-200">Parallax: -200</p>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h2>No Parallax</h2>
    <p data-swiper-parallax="-100">Parallax: -100</p>
    <p data-swiper-parallax="-200">Parallax: -200</p>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/k0b92hqkdeUR57t71RR4?p=preview

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Dominik No, even with Ionic 4 this seems to be impossible. I ended up using Swiper directly since I also needed other Swiper features that are not available in `ion-slides` like navigation arrows for desktop support.

Comment: I wondering what's different from http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/360-parallax.html? I discovered the source code and doing the same, but the Ionic wrapped solution does not work. (Ionic is using this swiper)

Comment: The problem is in [the HTML that Ionic generates](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/464ec3b70aca50266a01cf5e088eb65a7a4aa335/core/src/components/slides/slides.tsx#L482), which makes it impossible to add HTML outside of the `.swiper-wrapper` div.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by putting your background image to be parallaxed in the first slide, like this:

```
<ion-slides parallax pager>
  <ion-slide>    
     <div class="image-parallax">
       <img data-swiper-parallax="2100" src="url.to/image.png"/>
     </div>
   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
     <p> Other slide content </p>
   <ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And then, style the div as this:

```
.image-parallax{    
  position: absolute;
  img{
    margin-left: 200px;
    width: 2000px;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

And then adjust the margins, width and height of the background.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this with ionic 4, putting the background image in  and making the background-attachment local.

my.page.html:

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts" class="parallax-bg" data-swiper-parallax-x="-20%" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url(assets/images/background_'+category+'.svg)'}">
```

my.page.scss:

```
.parallax-bg {
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: local;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```